# Ayuda con un bucle que incrementa un contador en un diálogo en Android

Tags: android, kotlin

Tengo una aplicación que realiza la escritura por NFC en una tarjeta, depende del número que le haya pasado realizará un número u otro de lecturas. Supongo que esto lo hago con un simple bucle for, el problema es que no se donde colocar ese bucle for. Os pongo un ejemplo de la clase:

```
class HomeFragment : Fragment(), OnClickDetailsMonuments {

    private lateinit var homeFragmentViewModel: HomeFragmentViewModel
    private lateinit var homeMonumentsAdapter: MonumentsAdapter

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View =
        inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_fragment, container, false)

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        initViews()
        getObservers()
        onClickGoToMaps(view)

        homeFragmentViewModel.loadJsonFromRetrofit()

    }

    private fun onClickGoToMaps(view: View) {
        fbGoToMaps.setOnClickListener {
            view.findNavController().navigate(R.id.googleMapsMonumentsFragment)
        }
    }

    private fun getObservers() {
        viewModel.getNFCInfo().observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
                when(it.status){
                    AsyncResult.Status.SUCCESS -> {
                        NFCProvider.initialize(context, it.data)
                    }
                    AsyncResult.Status.ERROR -> {

                    }
                    AsyncResult.Status.LOADING -> {

                    }
                }
            })
    }

    override fun onClickFavListener(monuments: MonumentsVO) {
        homeFragmentViewModel.updateDatabaseFavoriteCheckFromViewModel(monuments.id, monuments.fav)
    }

    override fun onClickRowListenerExtras(monuments: MonumentsVO, position: Int, extras: FragmentNavigator.Extras) {
        val bundle = bundleOf(BUNDLE_MONUMENT to monuments)
        view?.findNavController()?.navigate(R.id.detailsMonumentsFragment, bundle, null, extras)
    }

    override fun onClickRowListener(monuments: MonumentsVO, position: Int) {}

    private fun initViews() {
        homeFragmentViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(HomeFragmentViewModel::class.java)
        rvHomeFragmentMonumentsRetrofit.setHasFixedSize(true)
        val layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
        rvHomeFragmentMonumentsRetrofit.layoutManager = layoutManager
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        (activity as AppCompatActivity).supportActionBar?.show()
    }

    private fun showDialog(title: String, process: String, titleButton: String) {
        val dialog = CustomSuccessDialog(title, process, titleButton)
        dialog.show()
    }

    override onNewIntentResult(intent) {
        val message = NFCProvider.retrieveNfcMessage(intent)

        if(message) {
            showDialog("Correct reading", "1 de 4", "Continue")
        } else {
            showDialog("Error reading", "1 de 4", "Retry")
        }
    }
}
```

Como veis el problema es que cuando inicio el NFC es cuando le paso el mensaje. Dicho mensaje lo obtengo de un servicio de internet y es el que me devuelve el número de tarjetas que tengo que grabar, que es el que tengo que recorrer, y como por un lado tengo el onNewIntent que lo necesito para el NFC y por otro lado el observer, no se como hacerlo para juntarlo todo y que cada vez que yo escriba una tarjeta de NFC me salga el dialogo correcto y al continuar al siguiente, el número del diálogo aumente: 1 de 4, 2 de 4, 3 de 4, etc. A ver si me podéis echar una mano. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Hola Isaac, por lo que leo simplemente agregando un contador como propiedad del fragment, bastaria, pero quizas no me esta quedando claro cual es el problema. Vos tenes que esperar que del server te habilite la cantidad de tarjetas a leer? en ese caso pondria un loading hasta que el server me informe esa cantidad y despues le pasas la pelota al usuario y que apoye la tarjeta en el lector. Por favor ayudame a entenderte asi te puedo ayudar mejor.

Comment: Efectivamente era con un contador, lo he realizado hoy aunque no tengo por aquí el código para ponerlo como respuesta. El servidor me daba el número de tarjetas que tenía que grabar y ya era cuestión de usar un contador y unos cuantos condicionales.